# What is the "group vector" of a user?

Tags: sudo, group

From `man sudo`

> -P, --preserve-groups
>
> Preserve the invoking user's **group vector** unaltered. By default,
>   the sudoers policy will initialize the group vector to the list of
>   groups the target user is a member of. The real and effective group
>   IDs, however, are still set to match the target user.

What is the "group vector" of a user? I couldn't find its definition by Google. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group vector is a term that refers to the specific set of groups to which a user has membership.

Basically, whatever commands that are run using sudo will be run with the effective user and group IDs of the target user.

Comment: Thanks. What does "vector" mean?

Comment: vector is a fancy word for collection or list.

Comment: Is there really a collection or list such as  a bit array somewhere for the groups of a user?

Comment: `/etc/group` contains all group ids (gids) and `/etc/passwd` contains the user gids

Comment: `passwd` contains the _primary_ groupid for each user (which was the _only_ one in olden days); `group` contains for each group (and groupid) all usernames that have that group as a secondary group, so this information must be 'reversed' to determine the secondary group(id)s for a given user.

Comment: @MiguelMota, "vector" is usually an (one-dimensional) array. It might have been that in ye olden days, when there was a smallish limit on the number of groups allowed to an user.

Comment: … or the doco could simply be using the wrong word for what (the supplementary groups set) is more usually called a _list_ or a _set_.